# Dynamic 3d matrix creation in c

Tags: c, matrix, heap-memory

I have to create a 2d matrix and in every cell I have to put an array the length of which is computed in a function, when I try the following code it crushes with the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. In my mind the matrix has N_Sweep rows, N columns and the last dimension is computed in the function.

```
double ***gamma;
gamma = malloc(N_Sweep*sizeof(double**));
for(i=0;i<N_Sweep;i++){
    gamma[i] = malloc(N_Sweep*N*sizeof(double*));
}
// ...
for(t=0;t<N;t++){
    for(i = 0; i<N_Sweep; i++){
        for(t_M = 1; t_M<(N_Sweep - i); t_M++){
            gamma[i][t] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (N_Sweep-i));
            gamma[i][t][t_M] = 3.0;
        }
    }
}
```

the prototype for the function is:
`void gamma_computation(double ***gamma);`

Comment: Aside : `malloc` could be simplified, say `malloc(N_Sweep * sizeof gamma)` for the first one and so..This is the recommended method too.. Second aside three stars are dangerous except when in armed forces !!

Comment: I don't understand the `sizeof gamma` part of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should allocate only `N * sizeof(double *)` bytes in the first loop, because you want N columns not `N * N_Sweep`, also inside the third nested loop you're allocating the the third dimension of the matrix multiple times (a memory leak) when you should do it just once before entering the loop.

So the code should be:

```
double ***gamma;
gamma = malloc(N_Sweep*sizeof(double**));
for(i=0;i<N_Sweep;i++){
    gamma[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(double*));
}
// ...
for(t=0;t<N;t++){
    for(i = 0; i<N_Sweep; i++){
        gamma[i][t] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (N_Sweep-i));
        for(t_M = 1; t_M<(N_Sweep - i); t_M++){
            gamma[i][t][t_M] = 3.0;
        }
    }
}
```